# Bypass certificate error in IE

Tags: selenium, java, webdriver

I have tried over and over again to get the Internet Explorer Driver to bypass bad cert errors in WebDriver.  Currently I do this:

```
driver.navigate().to("javascript:document.getElementById(‘overridelink’).click()");
```

And it works just fine.  But it's slow.  I read everywhere that I could add in my `DesiredCapabilities` this:

```
caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
```

But it doesn't work.  I've tried several other solutions too.  Is this just outdated, and no longer works in IE11?  Had anybody found a current solution to this?  Thanks!

Comment: Is the cert registered in IE and just expired or missing from IE?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

driver.findElement(By.linkText("More information")).click();

driver.findElement(By.linkText("Go on to the webpage (not recommended)")).click();

Make sure you have enable protected mode for all zones under Internet Options -> Security.